# Get commits for a repository with date filter using gh api

Tags: github-api

I am trying to fetch the commits in a given time range using gh api.

In following command, what options I can use to get required commit details?

gh api repos/owner/repoName/commits .....

Answer (score 0):

Since [`gh api`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api) command is only a way to wrap the [GitHub API `repo/commits` call](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#commits), all you need is add parameters to your `GET` query.

Minify your JSON date filer parameters:

```
{
  "since": {
    "date": "yyyy-mm-dd",
    "time": "hh:mm:ss"
  },
  "until": {
    "date": "yyyy-mm-dd",
    "time": "hh:mm:ss"
  }
}
```

And:

```
gh api repos/owner/repoName/commits -f '{"since":{"date":"yyyy-mm-dd","time":"hh:mm:ss"},"until":{"date":"yyyy-mm-dd","time":"hh:mm:ss"}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the 2022-11-28 API, as 'since' refers to notifications and not commits. I misread this as well since this is what I assumed everyone would use it for; it almost seems like a programming/design error.